# Transit through India on a tourist visa?

Tags: visas, india

I have a tourist visa for India, but my plans changed, so now I am only transiting through the Bangalore airport. I was told it was ok to use the tourist visa for this rather than to apply for a transit visa. Is this true?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Can you reword?

Comment: In general, it is fine to do this. Specifically it is okay in the US, the UK, Canada and Schengen. I don't know for sure about India.

Comment: note that the India e-Tourist visa , you can ***ONLY*** arrival / departure from Bangalore, Chennai, Cochin, Delhi, Goa, Hyderabad, Kolkata, Mumbai, and Trivandrum

Comment: CCazes, you do not specificy exactly which visa you have.  there are various visas for india .. "etv" "visa on arrival" etc etc - they are all different.

Comment: Who told you that it was okay?

Comment: Hi, thanks to all for your responses. I have an e-tourist visa obtained online and will travel thru Bangalore. If I ask for a transit visa now I will have to submit our passports for 2 weeks as the kids have french passports and we have not been resident in the UK long enough to get the quick 3 day service. I called a visa service company and they said it was ok to use the tourist visa.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a source to cite, but this is coming from my own experience.

The e-Tourist Visa is only valid if you use one of the designated airports. Bangalore BLR airport is one of them.

You can enter the country and leave the same day.

Chances are, you will not even need to use the visa for the transit. If your flight is only a few hours apart and you have both legs in the same reservation, you can. Make an airside transit at the airport. Bangalore is a modern city by Indian stands, and since you have already paid for the visa, you might as well visit the city. I am not sure if an unused e tourist visa counts towards your 2 eTV per calendar year though.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have both flights on the same booking so will have to pick up my luggage and check in so will probably have to leave the "airside".  Yes unfortunately it will count to my 2 per year  limit.

Answer (score 1):

The ETV is perfectly fine for transiting an Airport landside. In most countries a Tourist visa is acceptable for Transit as well.